# wpfToolkit : DataGrid Double click issue

Tags: wpf

I am using wpfToolkit:DataGrid in my application.

If I tried to doubleclick on the corner of selectedrow ,It gives null value.

But If I click in the middle of the selectedrow I am able to get the cell value.

Kindly help me to get the selectedrow cell value irrespective of by dobule clicking any place of the selectedrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving your cell a background color. Quite often the default background color of WPF controls is transparent, so they do not register things like Click events. For example, a TextBlock with a DoubleClick event to copy the text will only work if you double-click on the text itself and not any of the whitespace around it unless you set a background color.

This will also show you if the area you are clicking on is considered part of the Cell or if it is just Margin/Padding

Comment: Hi Rachel,

I have changed HorizotalAlignment and VerticalAlignment value to Stretch.
Then I am able to do double click any part of selected row.
It's working fine now.

Thanks for your solution. Thanks a lot.

Thanks & Regards
Kathiravan Murugan